# Using HTTP POST to query a Database

Tags: http, rest

Can I use `REST HTTP POST` to query a database, for which I am designing a `REST API SERVICE`. Basically my confusion is whether to use `GET` or `POST`. I want to pass some parameter to the query so I was thinking to use `POST`. But reading on net I found that `GET` should be used mainly if there is `READ ONLY ACCESS` and `POST` should be used when you create something on the server side

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. By convention, GET is used to retrieve information, POST for creating, PUT for modifying, and DELETE for deleting.
See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Actually POST is used for creating and PUT is for updating/modifying.

Comment: Create = POST , Edit/Update => Put

Comment: This info might be correct but it doesn't answer the question *Can I use REST HTTP POST to query a database*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render information based on identifier then you should get it through **GET**.

basically **CRUD** is treated with  **REST** by assigning dedicated http methods which are as follows:

```
Create => POST

Read => GET

Update => PUT

delete => DELETE
```

if you using POST for getting Read Only Information **there's no harm but You are violating [REST principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)**